# Google App Engine: manual scaling with one instance suddenly created multiple instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine application with

```
runtime: java17
instance_class: B4
[...]
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

It has been running as set up with 1 instance for years. Suddenly this night (2024-03-26 around 3:15 UTC), without me doing any change, it scaled up to 4 instances, causing various issues.
How is this even possible, and is there anything I can do to stop it?

[image: Sudden scaling from 1 to 4 instances]

Answer (score 1):

Update: all good now, after 38 hours, the service ramped down to one instance again. Meanwhile I tried to restart and re-deploy the service but nothing helped. Turns out it was indeed an **issue at Google's side** - see the [post I made over at Google's forums](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Google-App-Engine-manual-scaling-with-one-instance-suddenly/m-p/729873#M3514) for more details.